# Shortest/longest halachic hours

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shiurim-measurements

[Chabad's article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/526872/jewish/Hours.htm#footnoteRef1a526872) explains the “halachic hour” like this:

> The hour has a special meaning in Jewish law. "The third hour of the
> day" doesn't mean 3:00 a.m., or three sixty-minute hours after
> sunrise. Rather, an hour in halacha is calculated by taking the total
> time of daylight of a particular day, from sunrise until sunset, (or
> According the other opinions, from dawn ("alot hashachar") until three
> stars appear in the sky ("tzeit hakochavim")) and dividing it into
> twelve equal parts. A halachic hour is thus known as a sha'ah zemanit,
> or proportional hour, and varies by the season and even by the day.

My questions are:
What is the shortest possible halachic hour in New York City?

What is the longest possible halachic hour in New York City?

Would it be the same every year or one year may have a shorter “shortest hour” than a different year?

Comment: In which country/ state

Comment: In different parts of the world on different days the sun can be up for any length of time from zero to 24 hours (yielding 'hours' of length zero to 120 minutes respectively ), so I'm not sure what you're asking. Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: Edited for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with? You can easily Google sunrise and sunset times for NY for the solstices, so I'm still not quite sure what you need help with. Are you working with a "Magen Avraham" halachic hour perhaps? If so, which variation? Maybe if you explain why you seek this information it will better help us to assist you.

Comment: I’m trying to increase my knowledge on halachic references and measurements and I am curious what the longest and shortest halachic hours could be in New York. Could an hour be 30 min? Could it be 90? I’m curious to know. Different opinions of “hours” could certainly be part of the answer.

Comment: In NYC using sunrise and sunset, the longest day is about 86 minutes, and the shortest is about 46 minutes.  For a more comprehensive overview of tdee subject see.    https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmanim#:~:text=For%20almost%20all%20halakhic%20purposes,that%20period%20into%20twelve%20parts.

Comment: Every year is the same since it's follows the sun

Comment: @Chatzkel 86? Based on tables I've seen, it's about 76.

Comment: @meir Oops. Your right. I added 25 minutes instead of a 1/4 hour

Comment: How can I get this question open? I’m curious of the answers. I can edit it more if need be.